# Does a Form work like a pointer?

Tags: c#, winforms, pointers

Today I tried to create a reusable Framework, and I had no problem to do this... I created a new file "Game.cs" containing the class Game:

```
class Game
{
    Form Form;

    public Game(Form Form, int Width, int Height)
    {
        //Set Form
        this.Form = Form;
        this.Form.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.Form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        this.Form.Size = new Size(Width, Height);
    }
}
```

Then I add this file into a new Form project, `Framework_Demo`, using VisualStudio and it contains this:

```
namespace Framework_Demo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Here I created a new Object game using class Game
            Game game = new Game(this, 600, 600);
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe this is simple and my question could be obsolete, but why when I debug `Framework_Demo` appears **his Form** but also **with the properties I set in the costructor of** `Game` class? It's not a problem but I want to know what happens when I set: `this.Form = Form`. **It's really working like a pointer?** Can someone explain this behaviour to me? Thank You!

Comment: Yes, `Form` is a reference type.  I would add though that having a `Game` class which takes a `Form` argument is not a very good design.  Your UI is going to be very tightly coupled to this `Game` class, you'll end up making just about everything in your `Form` public so that it can be manipulated, and your `Game` class will almost certainly end up being huge and doing way too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Game
{
    Form Form;
}
```

Here the `Form` field is just a reference to another form, where you get that reference in the constructor of `Game` class. This is generally done to keep a reference to the owner form inside a child form. When you set `Form` properties in the constructor, you're actually modifying the owner form.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's working as kind of pointer by keeping *reference* to the form itself.

As long as the `game` instance lives, any change done in that class to its `Form` member will affect the actual form.